# Matching routes that looks something like `pages/1/2/3/4/mass_edit`

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

I want to be able to match an *array* of ids rather than a single id.

I have this in the routes file.

```rb
resources :pages do
  member do
    get "mass_edit"
  end
end
```

But as you can tell it only supports routes of the format `pages/1/mass_edit`.

I need the route to support formats like `pages/1/2/3/mass_edit` or pages/1/2/3/4/10/111/1111/mass_edit` and so on. URLs like this are generated by doing mass_edit_page_path([1,2,3]).

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this could do the trick:

```
resources :pages do
  match "mass_edit/:ids" => 'pages#mass_edit'
end
```

And then in your controller:

```
def mass_edit
  parse_ids
  # do your edit thing using @ids
end

def parse_ids
  @ids = params[:ids].split(',').map(&:to_i).uniq
end
```

The url:

```
/pages/mass_edit/1,5,3,24,63
```

Comment: Only changed from `:ids` to `:id`. Perfect answer.